# WPF: Drawing normalized polygons that resize to fit their container

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, drawing

I'm trying to create a usercontrol that is capable of drawing polygons on the screen. These polygons have points all between 0,0 and 1,1 (normalized). When drawing, the polygon should fill the space given to it. As such, a value of 1,1 would correspond to width,height in the container.

I've tried applying renderTransforms, but that results in the line widths getting scaled as well. The line widths should be the same (this is vectorized polygon information I'm trying to display).

Can anyone think of the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Ever found a proper solution @JoshG?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe Canvas control with appropriate StrokeThickness could be used

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Fill">
  <Canvas Width="1.0" Height="1.0">
    <Polygon Points="0, 1 1, 0 1, 1 0, 0" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.02" Fill="Yellow"/>                
  </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've tried this. Because ViewBox uses a render transform to adjust the size, this causes the polygon to be rendered at ultra low resolution, then stretched to fill the area.